# display table cell none in style tag

Tags: html, css, w3c

I might be missing something really obvious, however consider the following code (tested in Edge and Chrome):

```
<head>
  <style>
    .table td { display:table-cell; }
    .hide { display: none; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td class="hide">This is supposed to be hidden</td>
    </tr>    
  </table>
</body>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3r38c9yx/) as well.

Why is the `<td>` child ignoring the `display:none`?

Now, I know that, for example, removing the `.table` class or in-lining `<td style="display:none">` will get me the desired outcome (hiding the cell).

I'm interested in understanding the logic of this behivour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is the  child ignoring the display:none?

Because `.table td` is more specific as `.hide`. You ran into a concept called [css specifitiy](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity).

Take a look here: https://specificity.keegan.st

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 4):

The actual reason is,
You can't add both the `display:table-cell;` and `display: none;` to the same DOM property.
In this case, you're giving two different values for the same property where CSS gives the importance to the `display:table-cell;`

Check out the another answer given here which speaks about 'CSS Specificity'.

Two ways to overcome this issue.

One is adding the `!important` tag for the style which you want to apply that is a bad practice.
Another solution is adding `visibility: hidden` which will hide the element from the view.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `.table td { display:table-cell; }` is the closest css selector to the `td` than `.hide { display: none; }` so you can solve this by adding `td.hide { display:none; }`